# Run a VB.NET application with docker container (Windows)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, docker, containers

I am really new to the Docker Container and .net Technologies. I will try to explain my question as best as I can.

Scenario: I want to run applications developed in vb.net using docker container. I am starting slow where I am testing different use cases. At first I wrote a very basic application "Hello World" using visual studio 2015 as following. The application type is "Console Application" and Target Framework is .Net Framework 4.6.2.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("hello world")

    End Sub

End Module
```

I wrote a dockerfile and it looks like the following.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.6.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Release .
ENTRYPOINT ["testVB.exe"]
```

Then I went into the directory with powershell and executed the following.

```
docker build -t testvb .     ---> build successful
docker run testvb
```

output below was as expected:

```
Hello World
```

Till now everything is fine.
Now I wanted to test my next usecase:

Scenario: Copy a text file (test.txt) from one folder to another.

This is how it looks like in VB.net ,, Visual studio 2015,, type-->Console Application , target framework --> .net  framework 4.6.2

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
         "D:\Users\DockerProjects\vbconsole\vbconsole\TestFolder\test.txt",
         "D:\Users\DockerProjects\vbconsole\vbconsole\TestFolder\SubDir\test.txt", overwrite:=True)
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I run it using visual studio the copy operation works fine.
Then I wrote a dockerfile to test  it with docker run.
Docker file looks like below.

```
From mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.6.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Release .
ENTRYPOINT ["vbconsole.exe"]
```

Then via powershell I executed the following commands into the directory of project.

```
docker built -t vbconsole .   ---> build successfull 
docker run vbconsole
```

output was not as expected:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Users\DockerProjects\vbconsole\vbconsole\TestFolder\test.txt'.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyOrMoveFile(CopyOrMove operation, String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite, UIOptionInternal showUI, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at vbconsole.Module1.Main() in D:\Users\DockerProjects\vbconsole\vbconsole\Module1.vb:line 4
```

Then I figured out that my local drives are not mounted during the build process so I executed the following command.

```
docker run -it -v ${pwd}:c:\app\ vbconsole
```

output was still an error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: container f3c74e349f0d545deb42a6def3973eda9baed508274f156b44b04ae72f54f8df encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)`.

This is where I am currently stuck and need some help or guidance to fix this issue.
I am looking forward for positive reponse.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is you host machine windows or linux? and you'd better use relative path whenever possible. why do you assume there's D drive in docker?

Comment: @LeiYang my host machine is windows and it is running windows containers. I don't assume that there is D drive in docker. The D drive which I have mentioned above is in my local machine .

Comment: if you have no special requirements, i strongly recommend you try use `.net core` instead of `.net 4.x`.

Comment: @LeiYang I do have a special requirement because the actual application which I want to migrate later after these tests is developed in .net 4.6.2. 
Can you suggest me something for the specific error I have mentioned above?

Comment: i already suggested: relative path, .net core

Comment: Okay, thanks,  but as I said I am totally Beginner , can you please tell me how do I implement the relative path?

Comment: as a totally Beginner, you can either try relative path outside docker first. or try docker relative path with bash cp commands is enough. you don't have to learn both vb.net with docker at the same time.

Comment: Your work directory `/app` and the directory you map your volume to `c:\app\` are the same directory. Your volume mount 'wins' so in effect you're losing access to your vbconsole.exe file.

Comment: that was a good hint, but when I ran the command " docker run -it -v ${pwd}:c:\data vbconsole " I still got the error 

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Users\DockerProjects\vbconsole\vbconsole\TestFolder\test.txt'.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyOrMoveFile(CopyOrMove operation, String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite, UIOptionInternal showUI, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at vbconsole.Module1.Main() in D:\Users\DockerProjects\vbconsole\vbconsole\Module1.vb:line 4